# How To Save Log Files To Mongodb Server With Curl

Tags: linux, mongodb, curl

Wish to have a shell script that can save the content of linux log files to a mongodb server using curl? Keeping in mine that the script has to copy the content of the log files line by line before sending it to the mongodb server.

Comment: You would need to implement an api to interact with Mongodb using CURL

Comment: Any reason for curl? Maybe [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/) works better

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb does not have a native http driver as of 3.6:

> MongoDB 3.6 removes the deprecated HTTP interface and REST API to MongoDB. [Interface and Rest API](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/#http-interface-and-rest-api)

So you would need to implement your own API in order to use CURL.